# Which is better, setEnabled or setUserInteractionEnabled?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uicontrol, setuserinteractionenabled

I want to make a `UIButton` disable for user touch. Both `setEnabled` and `setUserInteractionEnabled` can do this. Which is better? How are they different?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`enabled` is a property of `UIControl`, which is the superclass for `UIButton`.  `userInteractionEnabled` is a property of `UIView` (which is the superclass of `UIControl`).  `enabled` has effects on the visual state of the object (grayed out, by default) and is generally the preferred method of disabling a control—visual feedback indicating behaviors is a good thing.

There's not much practical upshot beyond that. Code that interacts with your controls is more likely to check if buttons are enabled than if their userInteractionEnabled property is set. Hence using `enabled` is more conventional.

Answer (score 9):

if something is disabled it is grayed out.

if interaction is disabled it appears normal but you can't interact with it.