# How do you check if a UITextField is ENABLED in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to check if a text field is enabled or not in Objective-C on Xcode. (note: enabled is different from not empty)

```
if([_firstTextField.userInteractionEnabled == NO]){
```

Comment: you want to check if textfield is active or not??

Comment: yes. To enable it, i use the code below. but how do i check it?

Comment: try `UITextFieldDelegate`

Comment: Please define what exactly you want to check for "enabled".  `textFies.isEnabled` works, but I suspect you want to check for something else semantically.

Answer (score 0):

`UITextField` is `enabled` by default. You can use `isEnabled` Property :

```
if(YOUR_TEXT_FIELD.isEnabled) {
}
```

And further to disable:

```
YOUR_TEXT_FIELD.enabled = NO;
```

**Update**:

`enabled` is a property of `UIControl`, which is the superclass for UIButton. `userInteractionEnabled` is a property of `UIView` (which is the superclass of UIControl). enabled has effects on the visual state of the object (greyed out, by default) and is generally the preferred method of disabling a control—visual feedback indicating behaviours is a good thing.

There's not much practical upshot beyond that. Code that interacts with your controls is more likely to check if buttons are enabled than if their `userInteractionEnabled` property is set; it's more conventional.

[REFERENCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649264/which-is-better-setenabled-or-setuserinteractionenabled)

Comment: No that's not what I seek. I don't want to check if it began editing or not, I need to check if the UITextField is disabled or not.

Comment: check `isEnable` property

Answer (score 0):

The code I used was right, i just needed to remove the Square Brackets!

```
if(_firstTextField.userInteractionEnabled == NO)
```

ROOKIE MISTAKE.

Comment: Don't compare `Bool`s with `YES`/`NO`, use `if(!_firstTextField.userInteractionEnabled)`